# How to create Map<String, String> and Map<String, List<String> protobuf scala

Tags: scala, protocol-buffers, proto

I am new to Scala and protobufs. I want to create a object something like this

```
{
    "id": "usr-435-899",
    "type": "SALES",
    "filters": {
        "country": [
            "usa",
            "germany"
        ],
        "indication": [
            "delivery"
        ]
    }
}
```

So I think I cannot create the POJO like this in protobuf's.

Now I've created different JSON which is

```
{
    "id": "usr-435-899",
    "type": "SALES",
    "filters": {
        "country": {
            "value": [
                "usa",
                "germany"
            ]
        },
        "indication": {
            "value": [
                "delivery"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

So I've created a proto something like this:

```
message ListOfValues {
  repeated string value = 1;
}

message AuditRequest {
  required string id = 1;
  required string type = 2;
  map<string, ListOfValues> filters = 3;
}
```

But when I try to hit the api from POSTMAN it says 404 not found
Can anyone tell whats wrong in this? And Can we create proto for first JSON?

Comment: Protobufs aren't using JSON for serialization. It's a binary format.